# Finding the presence of given elements in a list using drools

Tags: drools

I am new to drools and need some pointer for writing one of my business rule using it. I have a fact called as "class1" with date as one of the variable.
As an input I am given a list of "class1" called as "List1" and a specific date "Today".
I need to check if the "List1" has at least one instance for each day in the past two weeks from "Today"

Answer (score 0):

Can you write a static Java method fortnight(...) that, given a List list1 and a Date today returns true if your condition is met? If so, the rule would be

```
rule "lucky fortnight"
when
   $list1: List()
   $today: Date()
   eval( fortnight( $list1, $today ) )
then
  ...
end
```

There are some algorithms that are easy to do using rules, and there are some algorithms that are easy to do using procedural programmming, and so on.